# Wordpress Login database error

Tags: database, wordpress, authentication

I have a site on my go daddy server that i cannot get my login info changed due to the wrong email in the database, so i went into the database and changed it and it still will not let me login. The passwords are hashed and I have also tried it with no password in the database with no success.

Comment: can you show a picture of what the database shows

Comment: username email password ID nickname user status

Comment: what version of wordpress are you trying to use @CHouse95

Comment: im not sure i can't get access anymore to check the site is still live

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4) to change the password copy the **WORDPRESS V3,V4 PASSWORD HASH** Field and paste it in the password field on the server and change the username the server should be using phpmyadmin.

Comment: right now I'm trying to set up the wp email so that it can actually send emails out